# C++ Continuous strange error

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#ifndef GAMEWEBSOCKET_H__
#define GAMEWEBSOCKET_H__

#include <string>
#include "GameScene.h"
#include "SWebsocket.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"

class GameWebsocket : public SWebSocket
{
public:
    GameWebsocket(GameScene* scene, std::string url);
    ~GameWebsocket();
    void onOpen(cocos2d::network::WebSocket* ws);
    void onMessage(cocos2d::network::WebSocket* ws, const cocos2d::network::WebSocket::Data& data);
    void onError(cocos2d::network::WebSocket* ws, const cocos2d::network::WebSocket::ErrorCode& error);
    void onClose(cocos2d::network::WebSocket* ws);

private:
    GameScene* scene;

};

#endif // GAMEWEBSOCKET_H__
```

and I get the error on line `GameWebsocket(GameScene* scene, std::string url);` the `expected ')' before '*' token` and the second error on line `GameScene* scene`  which says `GameScene does not name a type` I can paste the GameScene code if you need. What could cause the problem? It seems like I did not include `GameScene.h` but I did.

**EDIT**

Here's GameScene.h

```
#ifndef __GAME_SCENE_H__
#define __GAME_SCENE_H__
#define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1
#include <string>
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "network/HttpClient.h"
#include "json.h"
#include "GameWebsocket.h"

class GameScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

virtual bool init();

// a selector callback
void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);

// implement the "static create()" method manually
CREATE_FUNC(GameScene);

    void onGetServersRequestCompleted( cocos2d::network::HttpClient *sender, cocos2d::network::HttpResponse *response );
    void onServerRequestCompleted( cocos2d::network::HttpClient *sender, cocos2d::network::HttpResponse *response );
    void connectToWebSocketServer();
private:
    std::string serverIp = "";
    cocos2d::Sprite* loading;
    GameWebsocket* ws;
};

#endif // __GAME_SCENE_H__
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to post `GameScene.h`. The problem is probably in there, it looks to me.

Comment: You need to provide an empty default constructor (no parameters) at any time when you have your own.

Comment: My guess is a circular include path. Make sure that `GameScene.h` does not include `GameWebsocket.h`

Comment: Maybe you have circular includes? Try to put `class GameScene;` instead of that `#include "GameScene.h"`.

Comment: Agreed, I don't see a good reason to include `GameScene.h` in `GameWebsocket.h` over a forward declaration.

Comment: I am new to C++ can you please provide an answer how to fix this?

Comment: `class GameScene;` instead of `#include "GameScene.h" did the work, thank You!